# Jax-rs Regex path

Tags: java, regex, google-app-engine, jax-rs, resteasy

I have this Jax-rs service interface:

```
@GET
@Path("{id: ^((?!_ah).)*$}") 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)  
public Response getStuff(@PathParam("id") String id, @Context HttpHeaders headers, 
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context SecurityContext securityContext);
```

The goal of this interface is to catch all character sequence except for:

```
_ah/foo
_ah/foo/bar
```

Or anything start starts with `_ah`

I tried the regex in: http://rubular.com/

And from what it seems it works as expected. However my problem now is that when I access a the supposedly bypassed path I get this:

```
 Could not find resource for relative : /_ah/admin of full path: http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin
```

My app runs on GAE, so when running on dev mode, this _ah path is used for management `servlet`s on the SDK runtime.

What am I missing? Isn't it that when the @Path filter does not match it will bypass it? So why do I get `Cannot find resource` problem?

If I don't put: `@Path("{id: ^((?!_ah).)*$}")`  the servlets under `_ah` path works fine. Isn't it that the `_ah` path is already bypassed and should be accessible again?

Comment: What do you mean by "*If I don't do: `@Path("{id: ^((?!_ah).)*$}")` *? Take the method or the annotation away?

Comment: Also, your regex is incorrect. `^((?!_ah).)*$` will also not match `"something_ahOther"`. You should use `^(?!_ah).*$`.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks, but even with the right regex, I still get "Could not find resource for relative"

Comment: Yeah, but you didnt clarify. You say *"If I don't put: `@Path("{id: ^((?!_ah).)*$}")` the servlets under `_ah` path works fine."*. What is *"don't put"*? Remove the `@Path` annotation? Remove the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem while upgrading RestEasy to 3.0.10.  I had a @Path("{id}") and @Path("jobs") conflict that came from legacy code.  Because of 3rd party apps, I couldn't change my rest endpoints without a lengthy process.  Fortunately the regex solution did work for me.  Though I can't say why it didn't work for the original poster.

This caused me a few days of headache both figuring out where my problem was and how to solve it.  I share this in case you are in a similar situation and changing your rest endpoint isn't a viable option.

Original class:

```
@Path("device")
public class DeviceApi
{
    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    public Device deviceAction(..., Device device) {...}
}
```

Conflicting regex class:

```
@Path("device")
public class JobsDeviceApi
{
    @PUT
    @Path("jobs")
    public void moveJobs(..., Jobs jobs)
}
```

Modified DeviceApi class that works:

```
@Path("device")
public class DeviceApi
{
    @PUT
    @Path("{id: ^(jobs)}")
    public Device deviceAction(..., Device device) {...}
}
```

Obviously you can put whatever regex you want in there.  I only need it to ignore that single path so I used the KISS principle (Keep it simple stupid).